# can't adb into phone with broken screen and lock pattern

Tags: adb, data-recovery, broken-screen, pattern-lock, fingerprint

i accidentally dropped my Pixel 6a on the counter a little hard. it landed flat on it's back. no physical damage. but the screen froze up. i pressed the power button to try and lock the screen (which it did), but when i pressed the power button again to unlock it, the screen stayed black. figured maybe the phone just froze up. held down the power button for about 15 seconds to see if force rebooting it would work. nope. guessing the screen or something got damaged. replacement is on it's way, but is there any way to recover stuff from it that wasn't cloud-synced or backed up? i tried `adb`, but it's not showing up when `adb devices` is ran. when i plug the phone in, it vibrates, so i know it's working and on. but i'm guessing since i can't authorize `abd` on the phone (if i remember right, a popup happens) i can't interact. usb debugging was turned on a long time ago, as i used `adb` on it several times recently. phone has a pattern lock and fingerprint lock. i tried a usb-c to hdmi cable, but nothing shows up on the monitor (nor when i plug it into my Pixel 4a 5G, but it does work on an android tablet i have, so i'm guessing the phone doesn't natively support it)

Comment: Using pattern lock was a bad choice as it can't be solved without display. PIN and password can be entered using an USB keyboard. For that reason you should never use pattern lock.

Comment: @robert Not necessarily true, I had a RainMeter script that would unlock-on-click with my phone plugged in, and it can also be done through Voice Access as well.  Unfortunately, both of these require some setup prior to losing screen visual.